automate creation of Rays on plotted custom variable?
feel like maybe I'm trying to re-invent the wheel, hence pinging the community for any pointers towards any available snippets I could model after...
I have a custom indicator that plots a variable, we'll call it "myCustVar":
example:
p_myCustVar = plot(myCustVar, 'MyCustomVariablePlotted', myCustVarColor)
I'd like to have code that automatically creates Rays in a manner very similar to how I've seen some indicators create trend lines between two pivots of indicators such as MACD, RSI, etc...
In the attached graphic, my custom indicator is generating the plotted signal line(alternating green/red) and the two dashed horizontals ~near zero.
all else are manual annotation for demonstrating what I'd like to achieve.
Logic I'd like pinescript to do:
---Identify pivot high of 'myCustVar' above zero w/forward and backwards look inputs.
---Identify subsequent pivot of same type(peak, not valley) with lower peak value, excluding peaks within look-forward(using 12 bars in example) input.
---Create a green Ray using those two points.
---IF 'myCustVar' crosses above that green Ray AND subsequently closes back below the Ray, the second coordinate of that Ray is moved to the coordinates of the most recent peak pivot that it can be moved to that would not result in a cross of the Ray with 'myCustVar' plotted line.
---Same logic for pivot lows below zero, but in other direction, of course, using red Rays.
Walk through of visualized behavior(attached graphic):
The dotted Rays represent the Rays in their initial and stepped configurations, as time and 'myCustVar' value progressed.
The solid Rays represent the Rays ultimate configuration that they remained in, after the plotted line moved away and no longer was in a position to trigger the logic to move the second #2 coordinate for the Ray.
I may not be using correct terminology, but when it comes to 'pivots' of a plotted line, I refer to them as 'peaks' if the prior AND subsequent values are both lower, and 'troughs' if the surrounding values of a point are both higher.
The '12 bar' rectangles just represent the (input) minimum look-forward for subsequent peak(pivot)

(1) 'subsequent' peak identified following major pivot high, outside of 12 bars; initial green Ray drawn.
(2) 'myCustVar' value crosses up above, then subsequently closes a bar back beneath the green Ray, which triggers relocating the second coordinate for the Ray to be the point (3), the most recent pivot(peak) that can be identified that would NOT result in the Ray crossing the 'myCustVar' plotted line.
This same condition happens again at (4), which triggers a move of the second coordinate to again be moved, this time to point (5).
...and again at (6), which triggers a move of the second coordinate to again be moved, this time to point (7).
Point (8) shows the point at which the conditions to draw a red Ray existed, same process followed until ultimately settling red Ray to use point (9) as it's second coordinate.
note: in between (2) and (4) in the graphic, you can see where this logic would have also gone through drawing and updating a red Ray, but I wanted to show further progression in bars/time, and the last red Ray that would have connected that low in between (2) and (4) to the low at point (6) should become purged, superseded by the creation of the later red Ray that has it's #1 starting coordinate at the low just after point (6).
note: there is no new green Ray illustrated on the right, from the most recent high, since, according to my logic, a subsequent peak pivot needs to be found AFTER (input)12 bars. If/when that does happen, it would remove/purge the prior green ray. This pivot high being established as new green Ray would also be conditional on 'highest pivot high' evaluation using lookback, as mentioned in the first logic requirement.
Doable?
Would be super great to be able to find a working model of this somewhere to learn, and repro into my own custom indicator, but otherwise, I would be willing to pay someone to create it, if it could be created to work exactly as I've described.

"pinging the community for any pointers towards any available snippets I could model after" - That's not how SO works, it's purely a question and answer site.
